# error "ace is not defined" in angular 5 project

Tags: typescript, ubuntu, angular5, ace-editor

I am new to developing angular2+ and ace. When I was embedding ace editor into my angular app, I ran into the error that "ace is not defined".

The system I am using is ubuntu gnome 16.04
The steps I implemented it is:
1.intall ace-builds using npm
2. copy the path from node-module to angular-cli.json(most importantly, the ace.js from src-min-noconflict.
3. build an editor component, the code in the editor.component.ts is like this:

```
declare const ace:any;

@Component({....})
export class EditorComponent implements OnInit {
    editor:any;
    ......

    ngOnInit() {
        this.editor = ace.edit("editor");
    }
}
```

the console shows the error was thrown in the line "this.editor =....."

I have been trying some other recent version of ace but did not work. Does anyone have an ideo on how to solve it? I will greatly appreciate the help!

Comment: Feels like the ace js files aren't loaded. Have you checked the bundled js files to see if they are being included?

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel Hi Daniel, Can you help specify what bundled js files  you referred to?  I check the ace.js is in the ace-builds' sub directory. And the path should be right(because when it was wrong, I was not able to build the project)

Answer (score 1):

> ace is not defined

error can be avoided by importing ace plugin file in your component.

```
import ace from 'ace-builds/src-min-noconflict/ace';
import "brace/mode/{mode_name}";
import "brace/snippets/{mode_name}";
import "brace/ext/language_tools";
```